# Proof that $(\mathbb{R}, +) \simeq (\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \times)$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the additive group. of reals is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of positive reals. The obvious isomorphic is $f(x) = e^x$. I know this to be a homomorphism since $e^{x+y} = e^x e^x$ by the properties of the exponential function, but every proof that $f$ is bijective, including my own, draws on the properties of the logarithm function. For example, it takes the form "if $e^x = e^y$, then $\log e^x = \log e^y$, then $x = y$" to prove infectivity, and "given $y > 0$, $e^{\log(y)} = y$" to prove subjectivity. But this is circular, because invoking the existence of an inverse presupposes that $e$ is bijective, hence invertible.

One way to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, surely, is to invoke the fact that $\log(x)$ is an inverse, so $f$ is invertible, hence bijective. But my question is, without invoking the existence of this function, is there another way to prove that $f$ is injective and surjective? Am I wrong that invoking the $\log$ function is circular?

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me fix it.

Comment: How do you define the exponential function? You can’t prove things about it without a definition. A standard way to define the exponential function is “the inverse of the logarithm function”, with the logarithm function defined by $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{x}\,dx$. In that case, there is no circularity. There are other definitions, but how you prove things about it depends on how you define it.

Comment: I'm doing a problem out of Artin's Algebra, and I don't believe he explicitly defines the exponential function. The usual definition I had in mind was $\exp(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$. Using the definition you gave, though, I think I would only need to a prove that an invertible function is bijective.

Comment: That invertible functions are bijective follows from the fact that if a composition $f\circ g$ is bijective, then $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. Then from $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}$ you get surjectivity, and from $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$ you get injectivity. If that is your definition of $\exp(x)$, then you should prove that $\exp(x)$ is one-to-one and onto $(0,\infty)$, and that would suffice. You can prove that, e.g., by showing that its derivative is positive, hence the function is strictly increasing, and that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\exp(x)=0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp(x)=\infty$.

Comment: You have two great auto-correct induced typos in there! "infectivity" and "subjectivity" - please don't fix them: they should remain as a lesson to posterity.

Comment: Showing that the function is strictly increasing would imply injectivity, so I think I'm ok with that; but how then would I prove surjectivity? I want to say, intuitively, that it follows from continuity (and the limits you gave), but that seems insufficiently rigorous to me.

Comment: It indeed follows from continuity (which follows from differentiability) and the limits, via the Intermediate Value Theorem. There is nothing “insufficiently rigorous” about it.

Comment: The only thing that came to mind was that the IVT requires a closed, bounded interval, but I suppose given $y \in (0, \infty)$, I could create a neighborhood of $y$ and apply it.

Comment: Exactly. From the limit on the left you know there is an $a$ for which $\exp(a)\lt y$, and from the limit on the right that there is a $b$ such that $\exp(b)\gt y$. Then by IVT you have a point in $[a,b]$ where $\exp(x)=y$.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that  $e^x $ has an inverse, $\ln x $.  Thus the homomorphism is bijective.

You can differentiate  $e^x $ to get injectivity as well.  Since the derivative is always positive,  and the limits as $x\to\pm\infty $ are $0$ and $\infty $, it's surjective.